# TeraData Query to get min and max from a table

Tags: database, teradata

I have a table named `HMS_PGHL8_HQID_MAP_DEMO` and database named `UDMTOOL_STG`.

Below query fetches me reuired values.

```
SELECT udm_main.RECORD_ID AS  record_id ,udm_main.HMS_PGH_NODE_ID AS  hms_pgh_node_id, 
       udm_main.HMS_PGH_NODE_NAME AS hms_pgh_node_name ,udm_main.HQ_NODE_ID AS hq_node_id, udm_main.HQ_NODE_NAME AS hq_node_name,
       udm_main.NODE_TYPE_IND as node_type_ind,UPDATED_ON,UPDATED_BY,
       INSERT_TS  FROM UDMTOOL_STG.HMS_PGHL8_HQID_MAP_DEMO udm_main
WHERE op_code <> 'D' OR op_code IS NULL
ORDER BY RECORD_ID,HMS_PGH_NODE_ID,HQ_NODE_ID
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

Now i need to get the total row values whose:

1. record ID is min
2. record ID as max

Please note that below do not works,

```
SELECT MIN(udm_main.RECORD_ID AS)  record_id ,udm_main.HMS_PGH_NODE_ID AS  hms_pgh_node_id, 
           udm_main.HMS_PGH_NODE_NAME AS hms_pgh_node_name ,udm_main.HQ_NODE_ID AS hq_node_id, udm_main.HQ_NODE_NAME AS hq_node_name,
           udm_main.NODE_TYPE_IND as node_type_ind,UPDATED_ON,UPDATED_BY,
           INSERT_TS  FROM UDMTOOL_STG.HMS_PGHL8_HQID_MAP_DEMO udm_main
    WHERE op_code <> 'D' OR op_code IS NULL
    ORDER BY RECORD_ID,HMS_PGH_NODE_ID,HQ_NODE_ID
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

Requesting your help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Why do you tag `mysql` when your query seems to be Teradata SQL?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements, you want to get a result with only two rows? With the min and max `record_id`?

Comment: yes..I need only 2 rows...so i need two queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QUALIFY` to filter the MIN/MAX:

```
SELECT udm_main.RECORD_ID,udm_main.HMS_PGH_NODE_ID AS  hms_pgh_node_id, 
       udm_main.HMS_PGH_NODE_NAME AS hms_pgh_node_name,udm_main.HQ_NODE_ID AS hq_node_id, udm_main.HQ_NODE_NAME AS hq_node_name,
       udm_main.NODE_TYPE_IND as node_type_ind,UPDATED_ON,UPDATED_BY,
       INSERT_TS
FROM UDMTOOL_STG.HMS_PGHL8_HQID_MAP_DEMO udm_main
WHERE op_code <> 'D' OR op_code IS NULL
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
QUALIFY udm_main.RECORD_ID = MIN(udm_main.RECORD_ID) OVER ()
     OR udm_main.RECORD_ID = MAX(udm_main.RECORD_ID) OVER ()
ORDER BY RECORD_ID
```

;